# Fit a linear function of the form log(D) = c0 + c1t to the data points (ti , log(Di)), using least squares.

Tags: optimization, least-squares

[image]

In the table below, we list the public debt D of the United States (in billions of dollars), in various years.

```
Year 1985 1995 2005 2015

D    1823 4974 7933 18151
```

(a) Letting $t = 0$ in 1985, fit a linear function of the form $\log(D) = c_0 + c_1t$ to the data
points $(t_i, \log(D_i))$, using least squares.

(b) Use the result of (a) to fit an exponential function to the data points $(t_i, D_i)$. What debt does your formula predict for 2025?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be set up as a matrix equation
$$
\underbrace{\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1985 \\
1 & 1995 \\
1 & 2005 \\
1 & 2015 \\
\end{array} \right ]}_{=A}\underbrace{\left [ \begin{array}{c}
c_0\\
c_1 \\
\end{array} \right ]}_{=x} \;\; =\;\; \underbrace{\left [ \begin{array}{c}
\log(1823) \\
\log(4974) \\
\log(7933) \\
\log(18151) \\
\end{array} \right ]}_{=b}.
$$

Then the standard way to solve for the weight $c_0$ and $c_1$ is through:

$$
x \;\; =\;\; \left (A^TA\right )^{-1}A^Tb.
$$

Linear least squares is covered in a lot of different places.  Take [this](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf) for example.